# How to make a buffer using HClO

Tags: acid-base, ph

> If we plan to prepare a buffer with the $\mathrm{pH}$ of $7.35$ using $\ce{HClO}$ ($\mathrm pK_\mathrm a = 7.54$), what mass of the solid sodium salt of the conjugate base is needed to make this buffer? Suppose you want to use $\pu{125.0mL}$ of $\pu{0.500M}$ of the acid.

I know this relates to Henderson's equation, so I do:

$$7.35=7.54+\log{\frac{[\ce{ClO-}]}{[\ce{HClO}]}},$$

which becomes:

$$0.646=\frac{[\ce{ClO-}]}{[\ce{HClO}]}.$$

But I do not know how to go from there, and I don't know how to use the last piece of information in the problem: ("Suppose you want to use $\pu{125.0mL}$ of $\pu{0.500M}$ of the acid").

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Chemistry.SE! You should take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)  to get to know our community and learn how to ask questions. As it stands now, you title is way too long and unclear. Try to state *one* clearly formulated question.

Answer (score 0):

The information given in the problem, "Suppose you want to use 125.0mL of 0.500M of the acid." tells us that the molarity or concentration of the acid is 0.5M. So, [ACID] = 0.5.
Now, 0.646 = [BASE]/(0.5)
So, [BASE] = 0.646×0.5 = 0.323
So, concentration of conjugate base = 0.323M
       n/V = 0.323
Since, volume is 125.0mL = 0.125L
       n/(0.125) = 0.323
So, n = 0.04
So, no. of moles of conjugate base = 0.04
So, mass of sodium salt of conjugate base i.e NaClO = 0.04×74.5 ~= 3g
(Since, molar​ mass of NaClO is 74.5)
Thus, your answer is 3g.